# Не могу понять суть ошибки can сети. "network is down "

Tags: linux, c, can

В общем создал тестовую прожку. Для прослушивания CAN  сообщений.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/can.h>
#include <linux/if.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//#include <net/if.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <linux/can/raw.h>
#define offsetof_1(s, m) (size_t)&(((s *)0)-›m)

bool init_start(void);

int main()
{
   if(init_start() == 1){
    printf("init_start() return TRUE");
    }

    return 0;
}

bool init_start()
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    // создание can-сокета
    int s = socket(PF_CAN, SOCK_RAW, CAN_RAW);

    // задание структуры связанной can-интерфейс
    // struct ifreq ifr = {.ifr_ifru = "can0"};
    // ifr.ifr_ifindex = if_nametoindex(ifr.ifr_name);

    // связывание сокета с конкретным адресом
    struct sockaddr_can addr;
    struct ifreq ifr;

    strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, "can0");   
    // memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    ioctl(s, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr);

    addr.can_family = AF_CAN;
    addr.can_ifindex = ifr.ifr_ifindex;

    bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));


    system("ip link set can0 type can bitrate 125000");

    // отправка сетевого кадра
    //  struct canfd_frame frame = {.can_id=0x202, .len=2, .flags=0, .data={0x55,0xaa}};
    // write(s, &frame, offsetof(struct canfd_frame, data) + frame.len);
    struct can_frame frame;
    int nbytes;

    while(1)
    {
            nbytes = read(s, &frame, offsetof(struct canfd_frame, data));
        if (nbytes < 0){
            perror ("can raw socket read");
            return 1;
        }

        /* paraniod prowerka */
        if(nbytes < sizeof(struct can_frame)){
            fprintf(stderr, "read: incomplete CAN frame\n");
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            printf("ID:%d", frame.can_id);
            printf("len:%d", frame.can_dlc);
            printf("DATA:");
            for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
                printf("%d", frame.data[i]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }


    return 1;
}
```

А вот результат ;_;
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так и не понял что я делаю не так, так как связь есть сообщения идут. А код почему-то выполняется до выхода из функции инициализации, хотя должен постоянно выводить принятое сообщение.

---

<sub>Пытался этот вопрос выложить на stackoverflow английский, мне почему то запретили задавать вопросы и говорят редактируй свои вопросы ;_;. Там очень токсичная "атмосфера"</sub>

Comment: из проблем: как я уже говорил проверку ошибок надо добавить на все вызовы; `ip link` надо делать до создания сокета; `ifr.ifr_ifindex` не устанавливаешь и `struct ifreq` надо занулять перед инициализацией...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Проблема в том что я не вызываю `ip link` у меня есть только вызов `system`

Comment: дык, он должен идти перед всем остальным...

Comment: Его вообще не должно быть в таком виде — всё делается через netlink и другие интерфейсы.